# SharedPreference value didn't get update by new value in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

There is sharedpreference file which is store in the server which is copy and store to the /data/data/package_name/shared_prefs/file.xml file every time the application start, when any changed is made in the sharedpreference and next time the application is started the default sharedpreference file is copy to the /data/data/package_name/shared_prefs/file.xml  but the preference is assign with the last value changed not the default value file placed in /shared_prefs/, PreferenceActivity is used to achieve the sharedpreference feature. But if I restart my phone it works fine, there must be some garbage value store, how can we clear this value.

Answer (score 2):

`SharedPreferences` is a Singleton object so you can easily get as many references as you want, it opens file only when you call `getSharedPreferences` first time, or create only one reference for it.

So if turned off your application and Android didn't clear your static values your object will be not created again.

More about `SharedPreferences` [you can find in my article here](http://yakivmospan.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/best-practice-sharedpreferences/)

Instead of copying your object to Server try to create JSON from it and than send. And on application start, download JSON from server and put it in Preferences